# Using readFileSync after creating a file with createWriteStream shows empty buffer

Tags: node.js, fs

I am using the [`gif-encoder` npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gif-encoder) to create a gif, then the [`imgur-uploader` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgur-uploader) to upload it to imgur. Below is my relevant code, where `pics` is an array of filenames:

```
var gif = new GifEncoder(imageSize, imageSize);
var file = fs.createWriteStream('testing.gif');

gif.pipe(file);
gif.setRepeat(0);
gif.setQuality(20);
gif.setDelay(100);
gif.writeHeader();

var addToGif = function(images, counter = 0) {
    getPixels(images[counter], function(err, pixels) {
        gif.addFrame(pixels.data);
        gif.read();
        if (counter === images.length - 1) {
            gif.finish();
        } else {
            addToGif(images, ++counter);
        }
    })
}
addToGif(pics);

var sleep = require('sleep');
sleep.sleep(3) // I put this here because I thought I'd have to wait, but it doesn't work
console.log(fs.readFileSync('testing.gif'));
return imgurUploader(fs.readFileSync('testing.gif'), { title: 'Hello!' })
.then(data => {
    return data.link;
});
```

This *does* create the gif properly in my filesystem, but the `console.log(fs.readFileSync('testing.gif')` line just shows an empty `<Buffer >`! This means the `imgurUploader` function returns a 400 error since it's sending (what it thinks to be) an empty file.

If I replace the `imgurUploader` file argument with some pre-existing image in my folder, it works fine.

Why does `readFileSync` return an empty buffer when the file is indeed there?

Comment: I am having the same problem too!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but just had this problem and solved it. Here's my code

```
const getImage = async () => await new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => 
  streamVariable.createWriteStream('test.jpeg')
    .on('finish',() => resolve(readFileSync('test.jpeg')))
    .on(''error, (e) => reject(e))
)
```

The problem is that it reads before createWriteStream finishes writing the file, that's why it's empty. Using a promise combo solves this